# How to convert screen coordinates to geopoint in android

Tags: android, android-mapview, geopoints

I am trying to convert screen coordinates to a Geopoint in android mapview. I need to show a marker at the center of screen(mapview is filled in the window). So I tried to get the center coordinates using display metrics getWidth() and getHeight() methods and converted to geoppoint using mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(height/2, width/2). But it seems to be giving wrong results. What shall I do?

Answer (score 5):

You have passing the height and width argument as wrong change

**`mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(width/2,height/2);`**

try this code

```
Projection proj = mapview.getProjection();
GeoPoint proj.fromPixels(int x, int y) ;
```

here you have to pass the x,y coordinate and it will convert to the GeoPoint you can also reserve this from GeoPoint to pixel also from this object

```
Point p = new Point();
proj.toPixels(GeoPoint in, android.graphics.Point out)
```

check this link for more info

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/Projection

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking into account the `notificationBar` size? maybe also the `appBar`?

What you want to know is the width and height of the `MapView`, and then get the projection :)